# Should Authenticated Lighting Out App Not Run As Authenticated User Instead of Guest User?

Tags: oauth2, authentication, oauth, wordpress, lighting-out

I have a Lighting Out App hosted on a website and have been using this for read-only actions for sometime via an unauthenticated Community endpoint. This has worked out well.  I now have a requirement to provide some functionality form the Lighting Out which an authenticated user I thought would be able to perform.  To try this out in a POC I've created a Connected App and authenticated via oAuth to my SFDC sandbox to obtain a token which I now provide in my Lighting out Markup.  On performing actions from the Lightning Out App on my website I note it's still running as the Site Guest User. I changed the URL from the community endpoint to a Sites endpoint and it has not made any difference.  Should an authenticated Lighting Out session not run as the authenticated user? I thought I'd clarify if my understanding of it has been correct.

Thanks in advance for any help on this. It may be an error on my side in terms of my token but thought I'd confirm if the concept is correct.

Comment: An update: One thing I'm currently looking into is whether the token is not being picked up correctly. The App is still appearing but there's no error message regarding the token. I'd still like to know whether my understanding on which user it should run is is correct though. I'll provide an update if i figure out if the token is being ignored in my setup.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd provide an update on what my issue was in case it's useful for anyone else going forward.

After I received my oauth token I applied it in my Lighting Out markup while still using the Site endpoint for referencing the component. I actually needed to change the endpoint in the Lightning Out markuo to use the mydomain url to which I had oAuth authenticated instead of still using the Site URL.
I found it strange that it gave no error when I used a token and a Site URL (it just ignored the token) but anyhow that's what the cause was.

It works with the mydomain to which the oauth was autheticated.